# User-defined type guard that verifies if a generic object's properties are all not null/undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a user-defined type guard function for this use-case:

- 100+ TS functions that each accept an `options` object.
- Each function uses only a few properties from that object, and ignores the rest.
- The `options` object's type allows nulls, but for any of these functions, if any of its needed properties are null, the function must log the missing property name to console and return immediately.

My idea (which might not be possible), is to combine input validation, logging of invalid inputs, and a type guard into a single function that will accept an object and if any of the object's properties are null or undefined, it will log to console including the name of the null property.  It should return true if all properties have non-null/non-undefined values, false if any are null or undefined. And when the function returns it should serve as a type guard so the object's properties can be referenced without casts to non-nullable types.

Here's my first attempt:

```
type AllNonNullable<T> = { [P in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[P]> };
type StringKeyedObject = { [s: string]: any };
const allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged = <T extends StringKeyedObject>(values: T) 
                                        : values is AllNonNullable<T> => {

  for (const key in Object.keys(values)) {
    if (values[key] == null) {
      console.log (`${key} is missing`);
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Here's a simple example of what I was thinking for use of this function:

```
interface Foo {
  prop1: string | null;
  prop2: number | null;
  prop3: {} | null;
}

const test1 = (foo: Foo): boolean => {

  if (!allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged(foo)) {
    return false;
  }
  const { prop1, prop2 } = foo;

  console.log (`${prop1.toLowerCase()} and then ${prop2.toFixed(0)}`);
  return true;
}
```

But this code has (at least!) one big problem: it's checking all the properties of `foo`, where I really only want it to check the two props that this code is using.  Some of those other props might be OK to be null. I just care about `prop1` and `prop2`.

My second try was a verbose solution like this:

```
const test2 = (foo: Foo): boolean => {

  const propsToUse = { prop1: foo.prop1, prop2: foo.prop2 };

  if (!allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged(propsToUse)) {
    return false;
  }
  const {prop1, prop2} = propsToUse;

  console.log (`${prop1.toLowerCase()} and then ${prop2.toFixed(0)}`);
  return true;
}
```

But that is awful. It'd require typing each property name three times, and would make refactoring property names painful.

This final idea is IMHO the clearest and least repetitive, but sadly TypeScript doesn't realize that my type guard should be applied to `prop1` and `prop2`, presumably because the type guard is only applied to the anonymous object created while calling the type guard function.

```
const test3 = (foo: Foo): boolean => {

  const {prop1, prop2} = foo;
  if (!allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged({prop1, prop2})) {
    return false;
  }

  console.log (`${prop1.toLowerCase()} and then ${prop2.toFixed(0)}`);
  return true;
}
```

So #1 is a runtime bug. #2 is ugly, verbose, and error-prone. #3 is a compile error and, in the best case, might work in a later TS release.

Is there a better solution that will work on TypeScript 3.0? On 3.1?

Comment: Why are all of these functions sharing one big "god" options object? Can these options not in any way be broken down into common subset(s)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - my options example is actually a pretty big simplification of the actual use-case, which is that there's a whole bunch of types and functions involved, but the common denominator is that all these functions are passed objects where a subset of properties is used. Instead of creating single-use types or interfaces for each function's subset, I was hoping to be able to find a clear, relatively-DRY, refactoring-friendly approach without having to change these functions' callers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to pass the properties as strings to the `allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged`. Typescript offers the ability to have type safe keys using `keyof T`. Is a bit less verbose then version 2, and has the added benefit of not creating extra objects.

```
interface Foo {
  prop1: string | null;
  prop2: number | null;
  prop3: {} | null;
}

type SomeNonNullable<T, TKey> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends TKey ? NonNullable<T[P]> : T[P] };
const allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged = <T, TKey extends keyof T>(values: T, ... props: TKey[]) 
                                        : values is SomeNonNullable<T, TKey> => {

  for (const key of props) {
    if (values[key] == null) {
      console.log (`${key} is missing`);
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

const test1 = (foo: Foo): boolean => {

  if (!allPropertiesHaveValuesLogged(foo, 'prop1', 'prop2')) {
    return false;
  }
  const { prop1, prop2 } = foo;

  console.log (`${prop1.toLowerCase()} and then ${prop2.toFixed(0)}`);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: At least with your solution I only have to type each property name twice instead of three times! But I was hoping to avoid the refactoring and typo problems that come with a "property names as strings" approach.  Is there any way to do this without property names as quoted strings?

Comment: @JustinGrant it's something :-)

Comment: Yep. After doing more research, your approach definitely seems like the best option. Thanks!