# Type guard that verifies a generic object's properties are all not optional/null/undefined

Tags: typescript

In addition to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52531303/827027), I have additionally the properties marked as optional.

The following code does the type inference correctly, but the definition of the type guard returns the error

> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.

```js
type PropNonNullable<T, TKey extends keyof T> = Omit<T, TKey> & { [P in TKey]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> };
export const valueNotNull = <T, TKey extends keyof T>(key: TKey) => (vals: T): vals is PropNonNullable<T, TKey> =>
  vals != null && vals[key] != null;

type TTT = {
  a?: string | undefined;
  b?: string;
  c: string | undefined;
};

const items: TTT[] = [{ c: undefined }];
const xs: string[] = items.filter(valueNotNull("b")).map(v => v.b);
```

How can i define the return type of the guide so that it fulfils the requirement?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAOQQO2QVwDbYIYBG2EAPACoA0UZA0hCFBAB7ARoAmAzlANb0IAzagD4oAXigB5ALYBLYOSq16ogGRQA3lADaMKLLTU6IALoBaAPwAuKKgw58RUmV0nRAXwDcAWABQzMAQ4YCgAY3ROEIA3PGxMCFRgLFxxKEUjekYWNi5efiEyYQAKPhAbZRAASnFRIpjsTnLKm3ruWW54JDtkx2J0itExYT8oKFaoAEIJNAcoVXVW7VKTSemHH18-UEhqMjJUjRGoPGsoSLgDAHMoAB8oTA4IAQMIdg3RglPzq-ewm2+0Nc7g92E8Xm8-F4-H5wmhIvpWNJGrsXCsJNotKEbCCwWhXlB3CYNrD4QRkQDLto0QiIEiAHTPbCsOB1WLxRI9IoAIgIXMqlTp0jwYDqNTGdIIlWJERCeHJwAugKpqXktM4DNkTIgLPq7IQSQc3N5-MFwtFQ3FeCl0N8JIQxDp2AQlyKcqoZMqQA)

Comment: `vals: T | PropNonNullable<T, TKey>` will work. Ts can't figure out that the conditional type `Omit<T, TKey>` is assignable to `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has trouble figuring out that `PropNonNullable<T, TKey >` (which uses conditional and mapped type) is related to `T`.

There are two solutions one is to add `PropNonNullable` to the parameter type.

```
export const valueNotNull = <T, TKey extends keyof T>(key: TKey) => (vals: T | PropNonNullable<T, TKey>): vals is PropNonNullable<T, TKey> =>
  vals != null && vals[key] != null;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAOQQO2QVwDbYIYBG2EAPACoA0UZA0hCFBAB7ARoAmAzlANb0IAzagD4oAXmpQAZFADeUANowoASzTU6IALoBaAPwAuKKgw58RUmSVbRAXwDcAWABQzMAjjAoAY3ScvAG542JgQqMBYuOJQ5FS09IwsbFy8-EJkwgAUfCBG8SAAlOKimUHYnHlQAD6wiCjokebEsRr0wgVGZdwq3PBIJo2EzZStIKJiwi5QUF1QAIQSaGbSMl0KOVrzi2ZOzi6gkNRkZNGyU1B4hlD+cGoA5tVQmBwQAmoQ7LvTBFc3918+Ix-NAPGrPdivd6fFwOFwuXxofyqVgAWwqRysmwkCnk3iM4MhaA+UFsWl2CKRBHRwLuCixyIgaIAdG9sKw4KVgqFwo1MgAiAh8goFJkovBgUrFGZMggFcl+Lx4anAW4gunRFSozgslRsiAcsrchARMz8wXC0XiyUTaV4OVw5wUhDEJnYBB3TJKqhUgoOtTsgR4bzQABiCAQcnOYDqAEYgSr7o8lrgAdGkAAmIxLFEEfVJnZRuoAZiMsls+ZTMJcQA)

The other solution is to not use `Omit` at all, just keep `T`. In an intersection, the more restrictive  type will win out so for example `{ a?: boolean | undefined } & { a: boolean }` the optionality will go away since `a` is requited in one of the types, and the type of the property will be `(boolean | undefined) & boolean` which works out to just `boolean`

```
type PropNonNullable<T, TKey extends keyof T> = T & { [P in TKey]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> };
export const valueNotNull = <T, TKey extends keyof T>(key: TKey) => (vals: T): vals is PropNonNullable<T, TKey> =>
  vals != null && vals[key] != null;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAOQQO2QVwDbYIYBG2EAPACoA0UZA0hCFBAB7ARoAmAzlANb0IAzagD4oAXmpQAZFADeUANowoASzTU6IALoBaAPwAuKKgw58RUmSVbRAXwDcAWABQzMAjjAoAY3ScvAG542JgQqMBYuOJQ5FS09IwsbFy8-EJkwgAUfCBG8SAAlOKimUHYnHkFRmXcKtzwSCaR5sSxGvSiYsIuUFA1UACEEmhm0jI1Cjlag8NmTs4uoJDUZGTRsj1QeIZQ-nBqAOZQAD5QmBwQAmoQ7PO9BDt7h3c+Rk9oR6fn7JfXty4OFwuXxofyqVgAWwqKys0wkCnk3iM31+aBuUFsWnmILBBGh7wOCjh4IgUIAdFdsKw4KVgqFws1MgAiAhMgoFMkQvBgUrFPpkggFbF+Lx4fHAfYfInRFSQzgUlRUiA0sr0hARMzM1nsznc3ldfl4IVA5w4hDEMnYBAHTJiqh4gomtTUgR4bzQABiCAQck2YEQYAAjG8JYcTlARrgXv6kAAmIwjCEEZXhyPYaMBgDMRlktlTcwBLiAA)

Comment: The second one is definitely better since it allows chaining, i.e. `const xs: string[] = items.filter(valueNotNull("a")).filter(valueNotNull("b")).map(v => v.b);`. The first one did not allow for it. Thanks again!